# Use Sharepoint to maintain test results

Tags: sharepoint, testing, uat

I'd like to use Sharepoint to maintain UAT test results from different testers. I have a number of test cases, currently defined in a sharepoint list, categorized by 2 columns (Category level 1, Category level 2). I use these 2 columns as the two group by filters to users can easily navigate and find their use case. Now I' like to be able to store multiple results for each test case from multiple users. One idea is to create another list containing only the search results and to link the two columns to the other list of defined test cases.

Comment: I do not fully understand what do you mean by saying "contain search results"? You can create another list say "Test Results" and add lookup column to first list so when user creates new test result he should specify test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "Results" list with a lookup column to the "Test Cases" list. That's generally how many-to-one relationships are handled in SharePoint.